# Any tool available for Windows machine to check memory leaks in iOS apps?

Tags: ios

Is there any tool available for Windows machine to check memory leaks in iOS Apps? I am using Instrument on Mac machine with the help of Developers to check memory leaks but would like to know if such tool is available for windows machines so that i can work independently.

One more question: On windows machine how to check Console of the iOS apps. Earlier I was using iPCU (iPhone Config Utility)tool for that but then found that this tool is contentiously crashing for iOS 7+ devices.